# calculating null or empty value in Access report returns #Type! error

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

i have database which has Column 'Name' of the employee with "Surname, Name" like ' Gambel, Peter'.

I want to replace this name in report like ' Peter. G'. I have created a Vba function which converts the Name like as shown above, but if the field value is empty than it always return me  '#Type!'. I have tried a lot but still i am unable to resolve this error.

```
Public Function name_change(Name_pass As String) As String

If (IsNull(Name_pass) Or Name_pass = "") Then

name_change = "-"

Else

Dim Name_split() As String

Name_split = split(Name_pass, ",")

Name_split(0) = Left$(Name_split(0), 1)

name_change = Name_split(1) & "." & Name_split(0)

End If

End Function
```

Comment: If you just try `If Name_pass = "" Then` and leave some fields blank, do you get the `-`?

Comment: @dwirony I have tried but it doesnot affect the result. I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the answer.

In control source before passing the value to function we have to check the value is Null or not with NZ function.

=name_change(Nz([Name],"-"))

Thanks guys for your input.

Answer (score 0):

If not comma is present, *UBound* of of `Name_split` is `0` and `Name_split(1)` will fail.

Comment: in database there is either a name is present or its blank, and if any value is present than there is always a ',' in between.

Answer (score 0):

As Gustav points out you are only checking for an empty string, but not for one that has no comma. You need something like this:

```
If Nz(Name_pass) LIKE "*,*" Then
  Dim Name_split() As String    
  Name_split = split(Name_pass, ",")    
  Name_split(0) = Left$(Name_split(0), 1)    
  name_change = Name_split(1) & "." & Name_split(0)    
Elseif Trim(Nz(Name_pass)) = "" then
  name_change = "-"
Else
  [Deal with names that have content but not comma] 
End if
```

Comment: I know that i am not handling the string which doesn't contain ",", But this is not my problem. I have also tried to debug the code in vba and I have found that if the value of the field is empty than it never call the function. Access skip those values and goes to next value. I have also tried your solution but still no success.